# How to connect 100(more) databases which are having same tables and structure using spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We have a requirement.

1. We have to create the database/schema dynamically.
2. We will get schema/database at runtime and need to connect that database dynamically if it is already exist otherwise need to create database/schema and have to connect to it.

The structure for all the schema/database is same, means the table names will be same in all the databases/schema.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar case like you. I only can give you some source snippets out of my project and I hope that you get an idea.

1. Creating a schema dynamically

```java
...

// we need a datasource config from your current ApplicationContext
HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource) ctx.getBean("mydatasource"); 
var currentConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
boolean isSchemaCreated = currentConnection.createStatement()
        .execute(String.format("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS \"%s\";", schemaName));


var connectionURLString = currentConnection.getMetaData().getURL() + "?currentSchema=" + schemaName;
logger.info("connection URL with schema: {}", connectionURLString);

Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
settings.put(AvailableSettings.DRIVER, driver);
settings.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, dialect);
settings.put(AvailableSettings.URL, connectionURLString);
settings.put(AvailableSettings.USER, user);
settings.put(AvailableSettings.PASS, pass);
...

var metadata = new MetadataSources(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(settings).build());


List<Class<?>> annotatedClasses = ...
annotatedClasses.forEach(c -> metadata.addAnnotatedClass(c));


var schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
schemaExport.setFormat(true);
schemaExport.setDelimiter(";");

schemaExport.execute(EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE), Action.CREATE, metadata.buildMetadata());

schemaExport.getExceptions().forEach(e -> logger.info(((Exception) e).getCause().getMessage()));
    
    ...
```

2. Switching schemas at runtime (multi-tenancy)

What you want here is some kind of multi-tenancy which can be implemented with the hibernate MultiTenantConnectionProvider. Here you have set and release the database schema when you your application is asking for a database connection.

Comment: We have to create tables as well while create schema. Is it best approach to create a Stored procedure, which creates schema and table in one shot. please suggest me on this.

Comment: Yes, your approach is a viable option as well. It wasn't a feasible option to me because in my project are cases where the tables are also differently. 
I forgot to mention that the `annotatedClasses` are JPA entity classes which are used to create the tables in the database via the SchemaExport tool.